# how rails use time period for object to display?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schedule

I am creating some **Category** in my rails app. I'd like to decide when the articles will be displayed based on the different peroids of time setting. I'm looking for a better way to do this, since I don't think that using gem **whenever** is needed under this circumstance.

The questions I would like to ask are:

```
1.how to set time period for Category
2.how to check the time period(maybe use between?) when conducting query,
3.all schedules can be displayed like a google calendar(use simple_calendar), the entire schedule will be showed in my backstage.
```

The solution I first come up with is to create two date column in Category and define **begin time** and **end time**.

Is there any better way to handle this? Is there any gem specifically for this purpose or this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, a `Category` is a time period that a user can create dynamically. There will be some different `Articles` that will have a time period associated with them as well. The `Articles` will fall into a `Category` if the `Articles's` time falls within the start and end times of the `Category`. If this is the case the time period must have a start and end time. Something like the following:

```
# Category Class

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Omitting rest of the class..

  def articles_created_between(time_range)
    articles.where(created_at: time_range)
  end
end
```

You can then load a category:

`category = Category.last`

And find the articles in the category:

`articles = category.articles_created_between((Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)`

See Ranged Conditions for some more information:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions

Comment: thanks, I restate the circumstance:
1.the relation between Category and Article is Category many to many.
2.Category have own image and title, so website show image and title as an section, then user can click photo to enter an page fill with articles in this category. so begin/end time is on category.
3.does every time I query for category to check time is a stupid way?or  increase loading for server?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a method to the `Category` model that will let you filter by a specified time range. Checking the time for each query is a perfectly normal operation and I don't see it really burdening the server too much unless you are operating at a very large scale.